# Required class not working on select in template wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-steps, formwizard

I am using template wizard form plugin.

The select gets its options values dynamically appended on the page load event. I have added required class to `select`, when I click next button without filling any values in all textboxes and keeping select default (0), all the default validation

> "This feild is required."

of this plugin appears on the top of all textboxes but does not work for `select` (category field).

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" onsubmit="return validateform()" method='post' action="./?action=savebookdetails" class="wizard-big">
    <h1>Book Details</h1>
    <fieldset>
        ... ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">ISBN *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input name="isbn" id="isbn" value="<?php if($result != '') echo $result->isbn; ?>" type="text" class="form-control only-numbers required" maxlength="11">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="dob">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Category *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control required" onchange="fetchsubcategories(this.value)" id="category" name="category">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**In jQuery:**

```
$("#wizard").steps();
$("#form").steps({
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
            return true;
        }
        var form = $(this);
        if (currentIndex < newIndex) {
            $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error", form).remove();
            $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error", form).removeClass("error");
        }
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onStepChanged: function(event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
        if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3) {
            $(this).steps("previous");
        }
    },
    onFinishing: function(event, currentIndex) {
        var form = $(this);
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
        var form = $(this);
        form.submit();
    },
    onCanceled: function(event) {
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
}).validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.before(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: which plugin are you using? It would be better if you add a working code snippet or a fiddle and trim any unwanted code (i see php and fetchsubcategories function which is not provided in the question )

Comment: I am using http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#vertical plugin

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="0">Select</option>
```

remove 0 from value in select first option
New Code

```
<option value="">Select</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form validation with out using `jquery.validaiton` plugin. You should set class name same for all field.

For example:

```
<input class="form-control amount validate_form" name="amount[]" type="text">
<p class="validateError" style="color:red;display:none;">please enter amount.</p>
<button type="submit" id="fees_stream_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#fees_stream_submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".validate_form").each(function() {
        var selectedTr = $(this);
        i = 0;
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (!value) {
            selectedTr.next("p").show();
            i++;
        } else {
            selectedTr.next("p").hide();
        }
    });

    if (i == 0) {
        $('#fees_stream_form').submit();
    }
});
</script>
```